# Does Emgucv have BackgroundSubtractorMOG and BackgroundSubtractorMOG2?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I am using opencv now, I want to convert my code to emgucv because I am more familiar in C# windows forms. Does Emgucv have BackgroundSubtractorMOG and BackgroundSubtractorMOG2?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Emgu.CV-2.4.0 yes it does. (http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Version_History)
It is contain in Emgu.CV.VideoSurveillance Namespace
Have a look here http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/Index.html